Why does my internal SSD take a long time (about 30 seconds) to become accessible Windows 10?
When I resume my PC from sleep, a particular SSD takes about 30 seconds to become available (I can see the drive but Explorer freezes accessing it during this time). It otherwise operates normally (read/write speed, latency, etc). This behavior reminds me of waiting for an older HDD to spin up, but takes even longer.
It is a new Samsung 870 EVO 4TB. I also have an 850 EVO 1TB, and boot from a 960 Pro 512GB (nVME) on Windows 10. Motherboard is the ASRock X370 Taichi which I've been using for like 8 years. I've never encountered this laggy behavior elsewhere/before.
It might be a red herring, but the only thing I'm finding in Event Viewer that seems relevant is a single entry (event ID 129) from storahci, 30 seconds after resuming from sleep (reproducible):

Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort2, was issued.

I have never used RAID on this computer, and there is nothing flagged in Device Manager. The drive's details show it is at Location 1 (Bus Number 0, Target Id 0, LUN 0) which is a wholly different nomenclature, so I have no clue if it's even the same device as in event viewer.

What motherboard?

If the drive is new reach out to MFG for RMA
